# Rails rspec get:index returns html instead of json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rspec

I'm working on rspec for a web application. I have an rspec test that calls get:index of the controller and returns a json which I then parse for my tests. Below is the rspec code

branches_controller_spec.rb

```
describe "GET #index" do
it "returns the correct json response" do
  get :index, params: { format: 'json' }
  json = JSON.parse(response.body)

  expect(json['draw']).to eq(0)
  expect(json['recordsTotal']).to eq(1)
  expect(json['recordsFiltered']).to eq(1)
  expect(json['data'].size).to eq(1)
end
```

and this is the :index from the controller

branches_controller.rb

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: BranchesDatatable.new(view_context) }
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

and this is the datatable

```
class BranchesDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base
  include ApplicationHelper
  def_delegators :@view, :params, :h, :link_to, :current_user, :can?, :content_tag, :url_for, :I18n

  def view_columns
    @view_columns ||= {
      name:        { source: 'Branch.name'},
      email:       { source: 'Branch.email'},
      location:    { source: 'Branch.location'},
      branch_head: { source: 'Branch.branch_head'}
    }
  end

  private

  def data
    records.map do |record|
      {
        index_checkbox: index_checkboxes(record),
        name:           record.name,
        email:          record.email,
        location:       record.location,
        branch_head:    record.branch_head,
        basic_actions:  basic_actions_dropdown(record, record.name)
      }
    end
  end

  def get_raw_records
    if params[:action].present? && (params[:action] == 'archive')
      Branch.all_inactive
    else
       Branch.all_active
    end
  end
end
```

With this code, when I run the application, it works perfectly. But when I run the rspec, the test fails. Here is the error line

```
JSON::ParserError:
784: unexpected token at '<html><body>You are being <a href="http://test.host/">redirected</a>.</body></html>'
```

I have tried putting render_views inside the tests and also in rails_helper.rb but it still returns this error. I found a half solution that made the test pass. I downgraded the ajax-datatables-rails version from 0.4.0 to 0.3.1 and all the tests passed but upon running the app, the datatable throws an error

```
DataTables warning: table id=branches-table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

I'm new to rails and rspec all together so I might have wrong syntax or formats. If possible, I would like to keep a more updated version of the ajax-datatables-rails gem

Any kind of help would be appreciated. I will provide more information if necessary.

**EDIT:**

Upon checking, the rspec has the following code

```
RSpec.describe BranchesController, type: :controller do
  before(:each) do
    @branch = create(:branch)
    @user = create(:admin, branch_id: @branch.id)
    login_as(@user)
  end
```

The test logs in before running the test so it has access. I tried testing both the behaviours of ajax-datatables-rails v0.3.1 and v0.4.0 and tried to look for where the error begins. I used binding.pry to check each action that was executed for both versions and discovered that upon running the line

```
render json: BranchesDatatable.new(view_context)
```

from branches_controller.rb, v0.3.1 returned the json that I want while v0.4.0 threw the error

> NoMethodError: undefined method `to_unsafe_h' for nil:NilClass

A couple of searches showed that the method 'to_unsafe_h' is a command under rails. Why would it be undefined? I feel like there's a line I'm missing or just some stupid mistake that I just cant find. Do I need to explicitly define 'to_unsafe_h"? Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you using some kind of authentication in BranchesController?

Comment: @SebastianPalma are these authentications?


`load_and_authorize_resource
  skip_authorize_resource only: [:branch_users]`

Comment: Maybe, you can add the code that defines them to see if you can make them return what they need so you aren't redirected.

Comment: Sorry I'm not that knowledgable in rails. When you say add the code that defines them, do you mean adding the variables in get :index, params:{} so that it'll return those variables?

Comment: @AdrianPlantilla What we are saying is *we suspect* that your rails application requires users to be "logged in". But your test is running as a "logged out" user. So either you need to change the controller, to allow "logged out" users to access the resource; **or** you need to change the test to "log in" the user before calling the endpoint.

Comment: Is this correct? Is there come code (which you haven't shown us) that requires the user to be logged in/authorised? For example, are you using `devise`? Or `cancancan`? Or `pundit`? I suspect you're using `cancancan`, since your code contains: `def_delegators  ..., :current_user, :can?` -- which seems to imply you have the concept of a "logged in" user who `can?`/`cannot?` access a resource.

Comment: @TomLord I just checked the gemfile and it is using devise and cancancan. I'm going to look into it and see if there is an authentication for logged in users. Although why would the tests pass if I downgrade ajax-datatables-rails to 0.3.1 and fail on a higher version? I'm thinking that if there was an authorization, either versions would fail since it still couldnt access the resources

Comment: if there is any signin/ signup mechanism present , then you have to either authenticate your test request or bypass that mechanism  for test specs. good luck !

Comment: I have added edited my question to add further information

Comment: @AdrianPlantilla, as Ashok said I doubt that this may be an authorization/authentication issue. Can you comment the authentication and authorization parts of your controller and run the spec? If that succeeds, you can then call login action and add header informations in your spec to simulate a logged in user. Good luck :)

Comment: @sabharikarthik Hello sorry for the super late reply. I was sick for the past few days and was out cold. I have tried commenting out the authentication and authorization parts of the controller and have run the spec. It still shows the same error

Comment: ok. Just to make sure that the call from application and the spec are the same, is this the route which is called from application: 'server_name/resource_name?format=json' (this is the route called from spec)? you can also use 'puts' to print in server console to ensure both application and spec calls the same action.